# Prove that $n^{-2n \sin\frac{1}{n}} \sim n^{-2}(n \to \infty)$.

Tags: limits

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{-2n \sin\frac{1}{n}}}{n^{-2}}&=\lim_{ n\to \infty}n^{2-2n \sin\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp \left[\left(2-2n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln n\right]\\
&=\exp\left[\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2-2n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln n\right]\\
&=\exp\left[2\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln n\right]\\
\end{aligned}$$
Can we go on from here? It's likely to be a bit complicated...

Comment: It looks like you can do this by showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(\frac{1}{n})=1$

Comment: you need a little bit more - $1-n\sin\frac{1}{n} = O(\frac{1}{n})$ - will do and that and more ($O(\frac{1}{n^2}$)) follows from the Taylor series

Answer (score 2):

## Proof

$$\begin{aligned}
L&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{-2n \sin\frac{1}{n}}}{n^{-2}}\\
&=\lim_{ n\to \infty}n^{2-2n \sin\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp \left[\left(2-2n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln n\right]\\
&=\exp\left[\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2-2n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln n\right]\\
&=\exp\left[2\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln n\right]\\
&=\exp\left[2\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(n^2-n^3\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right]
\end{aligned}$$
Notice that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(n^2-n^3\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)&=\lim_{t \to 0+}\left(\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{\sin t}{t^3}\right)\\
&=\lim_{t \to 0+}\frac{t-\sin t}{t^3}\\
&=\lim_{t \to 0+}\frac{1-\cos t}{3t^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{6},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1/n}{2n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2n^2}=0.
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$L=\exp\left(2\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot 0\right)=e^0=1,$$which is what we want.

Comment: You can divide $\ln n$ by $n$ instead of dividing it by $n^2$. While doing so you need the fact $(t-\sin t) /t^2\to 0$ and this can be done without using L'Hospital's Rule. The other part $(\ln n) /n$ can be shown to tend to $0$ again without L'Hospital's Rule. +1